# Using NIS without NFS

Tags: users, directory, login, nis

I'm configuring several computers in a lab to operate with the same login credentials shared between the computers, but without sharing the home directories. I'm considering using NIS for sharing the login credentials. How can I configure NIS to automatically create a new user's home directory on each machine, without having to manually login to each machine myself, and without having to share the home directories by NFS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NIS is a way to obtain data (authentication data, path to home directory, …) about users (and other stuff). *Doing* things (e.g. creating a directory) is not its job. So I think you're looking in the wrong place.

Most unices use [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) to manage logins (not just authentication but also credential management, account management and most relevantly session management). The [Linux implementation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/) (and others) includes a module called [`pam_mkhomedir`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_mkhomedir.html) which does exactly what you want. Put this line in `/etc/pam.d/*` for each service that allows local users to log in (or in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` if you have that):

```
session    required    pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and noticed that the real problem is that accounting/session is failing because the radius user doesn't have an entry in `/etc/passwd`. I have solved the problem by using `pam_script` to execute `adduser` before entering the gdm session.